# Making a 2D gun spin from recoil when it shoots

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics, torque

[I am trying to clone the game "Flip the Gun" as an exercise](https://youtu.be/F4qD2HanBL0).

[Here is the behaviour I have so far](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-v3m69F_MVWQQrvUbENMo0djRnyBVN-D/view?usp=sharing).

And here is the code I am using:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    rigidbody2D.AddForceAtPosition(
                transform.position-recoilPoint.transform.position * recoilForce,
                recoilPoint.position,
                ForceMode2D.Impulse
    );
}
```

As you can see in the video, the gun is moving too fast and rotating too fast. It seems out of control. I am not sure if the way of adding force to the gun is correct or not.

Thank DMGregory for editing the question for me. I am new to this family so that helped a lot. :)

Comment: How does the current behaviour of this code differ from what you want? Explain in words what should be different.

Answer (score 1):

The default [`rigidbody.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) applies the force facing the center of mass of your rigidbody, so it will never directly cause any rotation. But there is also the method [`rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(Vector3 force, Vector3 position, ForceMode mode)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html). This method can be used to apply forces to an object which are off-center and thus will result in a mix of rotation and velocity, depending on how far off-center it is.

A good way to use this would be to create a childObject to your gun which represents the point where you want the force to act and then use the position and direction of that object as input for AddForceAtPosition. Here is an (untested!) example script. This script uses a 3d Rigidbody. For a game with 2d physics, replace `Rigidbody` with `Rigidbody2D`:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
class GunRecoil : MonoBehaviour {
    
    [SerializeField] private Transform recoilPoint;
    [SerializeField] private float recoilForce = 10.0f;
    private Rigidbody myRigidbody; 

    private Start() {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (recoilPoint == null) {
            Debug.LogWarning("You forgot to assign the Recoil Point in the inspector!");
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown(KeyCode.space)) {
            myRigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(
                recoilPoint.forward * recoilForce,
                recoilPoint.position,
                ForceMode.Impulse
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me! I tried your code and the result is like in the video i just uploaded and added to the question. Please check. :)

Comment: @FrankSun if Philipp's answer helped, remember to click the check mark so people know that this answer is effective.

Comment: @FrankSun The documentation says that the force point is the point in *world* coordinates, so you shouldn't have to subtract it from the position of the parent.